# How to copy/paste a table from LibreOffice Writer TO LibreOffice Calc

Tags: libreoffice, copy, paste

How can I paste a Writer table to Calc to see it full? It always cut down (hide) the borders. How can it be pasted to see the full area in the same size and same aspect? What do I have to change?

[image: Writer]

[image: Calc]

Comment: How did you paste the table from writer to calc? Is the writer content really a writer table or an image? The calc screenshot looks like you've pasted the table as image.

Comment: It is an editable table in Write. I'm using Linuxmint. Ctrl +c Ctrl +v. I figured out, that the Calc using the full paper margins. So, if I change the paper size  in the inserted table editing mode, I can correct it, more or mostly less. But when I save it and open again, it start to fill the border  are blue! And unable to export to excel.

Comment: It seems that the only "correct" way to do it is to use WPS Office :-/.

It gives the expected result (a proper table in the spreadsheet without DDE things, which can be exported to a .XLSX).

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me:

(1) Go to the document and click somewhere in the table. Then go to top menu item "Table", "Select", "Table". This selects the entire table. Right-click to get a pop up menu and select "Copy".

(2) Then go to your spreadsheet. Click in a cell. Right-click to get a pop up menu and select "Paste". Now all the data appears in the spreadsheet.
However, the formatting is lost, such as settings for border line thickness and so on.